# perl optionally load module only if available

Tags: perl

I have some rarely used code in my perl script that requires a module that is not installed by default (but it is a standard cpan deployed module).

Is there a way to optionally load a module if available and just disable some functionality if not available to make the script run on most default perl distributions if not this special functionality is needed?

Comment: See [require](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) and [use if](https://perldoc.perl.org/if.html#use-if)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a try-catch block (called "eval" in Perl) while requiring this module.

e.g:

```
my $zlib_available=0;
eval
{
    require Compress::Zlib;
    $zlib_available=1;
};
```

and later on:

```
if ($zlib_available) {
    $page = Compress::Zlib::memGzip($page);
}
```